# Set tabular figures for inline math

Tags: math-mode, environments, inline, minionpro

I have a command to set tabular figures for the equation environment. I want the same tabular figures for inline math, preferably allowing me to keep using $$.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[mathlf]{MinionPro}

\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{%
    \figureversion{lf, tab} 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
E = m{c^2} %here I have tabular figures
\end{equation}


In this formula, $c^2$ is the speed of the light squared. %here I have lining proportional figures


\end{document}
```

Comment: I have tried `\everymath{\figureversion{lf, tab}}` without success. I get the following warns: "*command lnfigures/tbfigures/tabularmath/mathversion invalid in math mode*"

Comment: It's my understanding that TeX uses tabular figures by default, and to do otherwise requires special coding.  Some of the considerations for dealing with different "flavors" of numerals are dealt with in the article by Knuth, [``Typesetting Concrete Mathematics''](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb10-1/tb23knut.pdf).